# Converting my web app to SSL

Tags: php, android, ssl, https

I have a server that is host to a web app that requires a log in. Currently this log in is very very insecure. So this is what has prompted me to want to switch over to https.

If I switch over to SSL will my Android app, which uses a http posting to my website,not be allowed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Android app will also work with SSL.

- Update your Android app to use the new HTTPS API address
- on your webserver you should forward every request going to http://example.com/login to https://example.com/login

This way, your current Android version will continue to work, and the new Android version will use HTTPS by default.

Comment: Thanks! Doing A little more research with this helped tons!

Answer (score 1):

Without any changes in the app this will not work if you want to use https only on the server side.

To use HTTPS in your app, have a look at this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html